# why I get "existing superblock read failed: Invalid argument"

Tags: mount, filesystem, volume-control, file-format

Facing issue while running `mfks.xfs -f -i`

$ `truncate -s 41943040 /d/backends/disk1`

$ `mkfs.xfs -f -i size=512 /d/backends/disk1`

gives error

```
meta-data=/d/backends/disk1      isize=512    agcount=2, agsize=5120 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=10240, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=855, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
existing superblock read failed: Invalid argument
mkfs.xfs: pwrite64 failed: Unknown error -22
```

Answer (score 0):

You're feeding a "mount point" (`/d/backends/disk1`) to `mkfs.xfs`. It wants a DEVICE (check `man mkfs.xfs), like`/dev/sdq`. Also`mkfs.xfs`won't work on a mounted disk (`/d/backends/disk1`).

Comment: but i am able to create new partition on this : `fdisk /d/backends/disk1` and it is not a mounted disk. It is a device created from gluster server.

Answer (score 0):

I have build and installed `xfsprogs` solved my issue

```
apt-get install libtool automake gettext libblkid-dev uuid-dev
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/xfs/xfsprogs-dev.git
cd fsprogs-dev
make && make install
```